# IntelliJ file new move Java Class on top

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-15

When I do a file new in my IntelliJ idea. I see a menu like this one

[image]

I want to see classes from Java and Scala on the top. I don't want to uninstall plugins for ruby etc. But these should not be on the top. I mostly code in java and scala and therefore want these classes to be one top.

Answer (score 0):

When I want to create a new Java class, I activate the "Project" view. Then I select the package to which the new class shall belong to. Then press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd>. This popup menu is shown:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure that the directory you're creating a class in is under a module source root. You can navigate to it in Project View, right-click on it or any its parent and choose Mark As... | Source Root